# How to change the text of the equation from input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the values for a,b,c in the equation when the users enter input digits from the text-box? Also, after that, is it possible to directly copy the equation to the function to plot box for the graphing part so that user don't have to type the whole equation into the text-box in order to graph a quadratic equation?

```js
var parameters = {
  target: '#myFunction',
  data: [{
    fn: 'sin(x)',
    color: 'red'
  }],
  grid: true,
  yAxis: {domain: [-1, 1]},
  xAxis: {domain: [0, 2*Math.PI]}
  };

  function plot() {
  var f = document.querySelector("#function").value;
  var xMin = document.querySelector("#xMin").value;
  var xMax = document.querySelector("#xMax").value;
  var yMin = document.querySelector("#yMin").value;
  var yMax = document.querySelector("#yMax").value;
  var color = document.querySelector("#color").value;

  parameters.data[0].fn = f;
  parameters.xAxis.domain = [xMin, xMax];
  parameters.yAxis.domain = [yMin, yMax];
  parameters.data[0].color = color;

  functionPlot(parameters);
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
 text-align: center;

}
h2{
text-align: center;
}
.layer{
width: 70%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

section {
border:4px solid grey;
border-radius:15px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
float:left;
height:360px;
padding: 20px;
margin:10px;
}

#plotSettings {
width:160px;
}

#plot {
width:550px;
}
#extra{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Quadratic calculator</title>
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/js/function-plot.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="display">
    <var class="displayLetters" id="displayA">a</var>x<sup>2</sup> + <var id="displayB" class="displayLetters">b</var>x + <var class="displayLetters" id="displayC">c</var>
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBtns">

    <p>A: <input oninput="updateText('inputA','displayA','a')" class="numberInputs" type="number" id="inputA"><br><br></p>
  <p>B: <input oninput="updateText('inputB','displayB','b')" class="numberInputs" type="number" id="inputB"><br><br></p>
  <p>C: <input oninput="updateText('inputC','displayC','c')" class="numberInputs" type="number" id="inputC"><br></p>

 </div>

 </div>
 <body onload="plot();">

   <div class="layer">
   <section id="plotSettings">
     <label for="xMin">xMin: </label> value: <input type=number id="xMin" value=-5 step=5 oninput="plot();">
     <p></p>
     <label for="xMin">xMax: </label> value: <input type=number id="xMax" value=5 step=5 oninput="plot();">
     <p></p>
     <label for="yMin">yMin: </label> value: <input type=number id="yMin" value=-5 step=5 oninput="plot();">
     <p></p>
     <label for="yMax">yMax: </label> value: <input type=number id="yMax" value=5 step=5 oninput="plot();">
     <p></p>
     <label for="color">Color: </label> value: <input type=color id="color" onchange="plot();">
     <p></p>
     <label for="function">Function to plot: </label>
     <input id="function" type="text" value="sin(x)" onchange="plot();">
     <p></p>
     <button onclick="plot();">GRAPH!</button>
</div>
   </section>


    <section id="plot">
      <div id="myFunction"></div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, HTML has only one body tag and you have used two body tags.

After that do this-

```
<var class="displayLetters" id="displayA">a</var>x<sup>2</sup> + <var id="displayB" class="displayLetters">b</var>x + 
<var class="displayLetters" id="displayC">c</var>
    <p>A: <input   class="numberInputs" type="number" id="inputA" ><br><br></p>
        <p>B:   <input  class="numberInputs" type="number" id="inputB"><br><br></p>
        <p>C:   <input   class="numberInputs" type="number" id="inputC"><br></p>
```

in JS

```
     $("#inputA").blur(function a(){
 var e=$("#inputA").val();

$("#displayA").html(e);
 });

     $("#inputB").blur(function a(){
 var e=$("#inputB").val();

$("#displayB").html(e);
 });


 $("#inputC").blur(function a(){
 var e=$("#inputC").val();

$("#displayC").html(e);
 });
```

Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sp73612d/2/)